# I cannot get a div to take up the whole browser window

Tags: css, css-position, border, margins

I'm trying to get the border of a div to be flush with the browser window edge.

I've loaded up a number of css-resets; cleared everything on the page except a test line [of text] - and the border seems to disappear off the page edge -> almost as if 'box-sizing: border-box' was not working. I've tried everything along the lines of margin: 0 to get this margin to go away.
I've tried position: fixed as well as position: absolute

[image]

Master.css is the only stylesheet loaded, no inline overrides.

.. the reset has html etc etc etc 
extract from - master.css

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3 .......
{
      margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

#wholePageDiv {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 99%;
    min-width: 99%;
}
```

```html
then the html
<div id='wholePageDiv'>
Test text<br>
</div>
```

The blue border is not flush with the browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the div to be 100% high, the body and html must be set to 100%
It's worth reading what a [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) is

```css
*,
 :after,
 :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wholePageDiv {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='wholePageDiv'>
  Test text<br>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much. This made it obvious to me (as it should have been before) that my div is still a child of 'body' so any errant setting there would mess up all the good work elsewhere. I had a look at the box-model thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    position: fixed;
    height: 99.8%;
    width: 99.9%;
```

Comment: sorted with Grzegorz but the auto was a good rminder, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on my browser:

```
#wholePageDiv {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    min-height: calc(100% - 2px);
    min-width: calc(100% - 2px);
}
```

Basically using calc to set the height/width to be 100% minus the width of the border on left/right & top/bottom

Comment: @Connor Henna What you showed is anti pattern. First, I reset all elements with this code `*, :after, :before {  box-sizing: border-box;}`
This is used because each browser imposes its own padding, margins, etc.
Later I add to html and body height 100% now every div which will be set to 100% body will have expanded to the max. It is not necessary to use fixed and calc

Comment: Thanks @Conor. The calc will be useful for another place in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }
```